Cannot log into public wifi (ubuntu 24.04)
I can open the log in page to the wifi (captive portal), however once i click log in, when the wifi goes to redirect me too finish me logging in, firefox displays "server not found" and i end up not logged in to the wifi, is there any fix?

First, make sure network.captive-portal-service.enabled is set to true in about:config
Next, try to make a random google search. Just mash some keys in your URL bar and press enter. Hopefully, it will automatically redirect you to the captive portal.
Finally, try visiting http://detectportal.firefox.com/canonical.html to detect the captive portal.
More information at Mozilla.

Also, see this related answer.
